# Git Flow fetch feature branch onto staging server

Tags: git-branch, git-flow

Okay there are many posts similar to this but I am still a little confused.

I am using Git Flow.
I have a staging server with with master and develop bracnhes, currently on develop.
I use bitbucket as a repo. I have a new feature/new-branch locally that I have pushed to the repo.
I want to pull or fetch the feature/new-branch to the staging server for testing. So, it would look like this...
feature/new-branch
*develop (current branch)
master

I have tried git pull feature/new-branch, git fetch feature/new-branch with errors.
I tried git fetch origin feature/new-branch -- this actually said it fetch->head -- however when I git branch I do not see it.

How can I get the feature/new-branch onto the staging server to review?

Many thanks. Still studying and learning.
Peace
Tim

Answer (score 1):

Okay it took an explanation from someone to help bring it home.

So, git pull did bring the branch in question onto the staging server. I had to do a 'git branch -a' to list all the other branches. Ex:

```
* develop
master
remotes/origin/feature/new-branch
remotes/origin/feature/other-branch
```

So to then check that branch out you need to run:

```
git checkout -b feature/new-branch remotes/origin/feature/new-branch
```

That brought the branch in. I know see the documentation is correct just the one step of not seeing it and somewhat having to learn more about the terminology. Hope it helps someone else. Peace